# Given digits separated into array elements, how can I reassemble the number in an int?

Tags: c++

Ok I want to change numbers of int tab[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; to 1234 number, what's wrong in my code? It shows me 1232

```
int main()
{
    int iloscliczb = 4;
    int tab[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int j = 10;
    int zmienna = 0;


    for( int z = 1, i = 0, k = 2; z < iloscliczb; z++, i++, k++)
    {
        zmienna = zmienna + ( tab[iloscliczb - k] *  j );
        j = pow(10, z+1);
    }

    zmienna = zmienna + ( tab[iloscliczb - 1] );
    cout << zmienna << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please make titles relevant to the question. How is anyone else with this problem supposed to find this question?

Comment: Could you explain what your algorithm does as I don't follow the logic.

Comment: Well it combines numbers of tab[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4} in one number 1234, but it didn't work perfect, it shows me result 1232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over complicating this. Just start at 0 and do powers of 10^((n-1)-i). Like so...

```
int n = 4; // the number of elements in the arr.
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sum += (arr[i] * pow(10, (n-1)-i)); // here (n-1) = 3
std::cout << sum;
```

Comment: note that you'd be better off with an integer power function to get exact results. But in that case, beware of integer/long overflow and use `lonh long`

Answer (score 0):

It's easier - and more efficient as you can ditch the `pow()` calls - to work backwards through the array:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = std::extent<decltype(arr)>::value; i--; )
    (sum *= 10) += arr[i];
std::cout << sum << '\n';
```

Comment: `std::cout << sum << '\0';`  you mean `\n` right? I'd suggest to use `long long` if the initial value of i can be big to avoid integer overflow

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: yes indeed - thanks.  A programmer can definitely use `long long` if they think it's sensible for their usage, though on *some* systems it'll be slower to deal with longer types; `int` is intended to be selected by an implementation for general-purpose efficiency.  And, if `int` doesn't suffice, it may be that large-integer support like [gmp](https://gmplib.org/) - or a floating point value - is a better fit for a specific use case.